# using urllib.request to query a url with a range of x-api-key headers

Tags: python-3.x, http-headers, urllib

I am given a url/port and have to use python 3.8 to obtain a response from a server. The "server" requires an "x-api-key" as a password and will not display information without the correct key. (this is at least what I have gotten from it)

The key supposedly is between 5500 and 5600.
I am very new to python and wondering why my code is returning nothing.
Am I using headers wrong?
I've been trying things/googling for several hours.

```
# Alien Signal API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8082
# Use HTTP GET with x-api-key header to get signal
# We have narrowed down the key to be in the range of 5500 to 5600
# Note: The script can timeout if this occurs try narrowing
# down your search
#
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082"
startingKey = 5500
endingKey = 5600
hdr = {}

while startingKey <= endingKey:
    hdr = { 'x-api-key' : str(startingKey) }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    response.read()
    startingKey = startingKey + 1
```

Comment: What is this Alien Signal API? It looks like you're hitting localhost, so I'm guessing it's part of some software or copy of an API you downloaded and are running.

Comment: It's for a contest

Comment: cyberstart game isnt a contest its just a series of puzzles, the contest isn't till april.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you got most of it right, you forgot to print. Just add this line of code instead of "response.read()":

```
print(response.read())
```

or you could do this:

```
html = response.read()
print(html)
```